# Why can't I see caption when inserting image in markdown cell in jupyter notebook?

Tags: image, jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter, caption

I am quite new to Jupyter Notebooks and I was trying to figure out how to insert an image with a caption into a markdown cell. After a little search I found this command that should work:

```
![alt text](imagename.png "Title")
```

However, I am getting only the image without caption and title.

The code I am running is:

```
![My caption](files/RGBvsHSV.jpg "RGB and HSV colour spaces")
```

The result is the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWLmo.png)

The funny thing is that if it does not find the image, then it displays the text of the caption (not the title though). Anyone could help me?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem when I try to insert an image with a caption into a markdown cell. I get also the same result, such that if it does not find the image, then it displays the text of the caption (not the title though). Therefore I upvote the original post.